# Why do I fail in exposing a collection on MongoDB Compass to a REST API using Java?

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, nosql

So I've got this school assignment where I'm creating my own web based REST API using Java. I've got a database in MongoDB Compass called "mflix" which contains the collection I'm trtying to expose to my REST API. I've created a Java application identical to that of my fellow students and my teacher in order to create the connection but everytime I use Postman to check my url i get this return message:
[Return Message in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFe0e.png)
"It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port."

I've done some googling on this matter any I see many that claims that this is because port 27017 cant be used for this since the default port cant speak with the http protocol. Then how come port 27017 work for all my course mates and my teacher?

This is my connection properties:
[Connection Properties file in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZabA.png)

This is the url I use in Postman:
[Postman url and return message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QYhO.png)

And here is my Java code:

```
import static spark.Spark.get;
import static spark.Spark.post;
import static spark.Spark.delete;
import static spark.Spark.put;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;

public class RestClient {
    
    private void runDatabase() {
        String propertyString;
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( RestClient.class );
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream( "connection.properties" ) ) {

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load( input );
            propertyString = properties.getProperty( "db.connection_string" );
            logger.info( propertyString );

            ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString( propertyString );
            MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder().applyConnectionString( connectionString ).build();
            MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create( settings );
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase( properties.getProperty( "db.name" ) );
            System.out.println("hello");
            
            get( "/title/:title", ( request, response ) -> {
                System.out.println("hello igen");
                MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection( "movies" );
                String filter = request.params( "title" ).toLowerCase();
                filter = WordUtils.capitalizeFully( filter );
                logger.info( "Filtering movies for the title: " + filter );
                Document myDocument = collection.findOneAndDelete( Filters.eq( "title", filter ) );
                
                if( myDocument != null ) {
                    myDocument.remove( "_id" );
                } else {
                    response.status(404);
                    return ( "<html><body><h1>Movie not found.</h1></body></html>" );
                }
                
                return myDocument.toJson();
            } );        

        } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        RestClient restClient = new RestClient();
        restClient.runDatabase();
    }

}
```

When I run this in Eclipse this is my console/logger:
[Eclipse console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEEUK.png)

As I said I use Compass to connect with my database, Java to create the connection, and Postman to test the url.

I've tried to change my port to 28017 in Compass but then I just get this error message : "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28017".

Comment: `27017` is the port that MongoDB is listening on. Your API connects to MongoDB, and listens for connections on a different port. You should make requests to your API, not MongoDB directly. Do you know what port your API is listening for connections on?

Comment: Probably 8080? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20you%20can%20access,or%20via%20command%2Dline%20options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand what the problem was! Turns out I was listening on port 4567 which was hidden in the output from the logger the whole time!